# change list.map return type from list to an JsonArray

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda, java-stream

I am looking for a way to change the return type of `.map` function from list to JsonArray(google gson).

For example

```
    val a = listOf("Sui", "Pran").map {
        "Hello $it"
    }
```

this code returns `List<String>` but what I would like is, it to return a JsonArray(google gson). I dont want to `foreach` and add one by one it would be good to use `lambda, .map etc...`

thank you

Comment: That would be terribly confusing: map() is a standard List extension function, and any developer expects it to return a List. Hiding it with your own map() function would be extremely annoying and confusing. But you can define your own extension function and name it mapToJsonArray if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

Gson seems to lack a built-in way to do this. You could write your own function to do it:

```
fun Iterable<String>.toJsonArray() = 
    map { JsonPrimitive(it) }.fold(JsonArray()) { acc, el -> acc.apply { add(el) } }
```